# Using nchar function on factor variables

Tags: r

can somebody explain to me what's going on here ? when a variable is coded as a factor and nchar coerces to a character, why can't that function effectively count the number of characters ?

```
> x <- c("73210", "73458", "73215", "72350")
> nchar(x)
[1] 5 5 5 5
> 
> x <- factor(x)
> nchar(x)
[1] 1 1 1 1
> 
> nchar(as.character(x))
[1] 5 5 5 5
```

thanks.

Comment: If you type ?nchar you'll see that it acts on character vectors not on vectors of the class factor.  It will also act on numeric vectors but less predictably [see nchar(mtcars$disp)]

Comment: The `str_length` function in stringr avoids this annoying bug (and the annoying NA behaviour)

Answer (score 5):

It is because with a factor, your data is represented by  1, 2, etc. What you mean to do is count the characters of the levels:

```
> nchar(levels(x)[x])
[1] 5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 2):

see the warning section of `?factor`:

```
The interpretation of a factor depends on both the codes and the
 ‘"levels"’ attribute.  Be careful only to compare factors with the
 same set of levels (in the same order).  In particular,
 ‘as.numeric’ applied to a factor is meaningless, and may happen by
 implicit coercion.  To transform a factor ‘f’ to approximately its
 original numeric values, ‘as.numeric(levels(f))[f]’ is recommended
 and slightly more efficient than ‘as.numeric(as.character(f))’.

nchar(levels(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct, I think, that the issue is that `nchar` is examining the underlying integer codes, not the labels. However, what I think most directly addresses your question is this piece from `?nchar`:

> The internal equivalent of the default method of as.character is
>   performed on x (so there is no method dispatch)

I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect this means that the coercion that takes place in `nchar` is *not* the same thing that happens when you directly call `as.character`, most likely going directly to the integer codes, rather than "smartly" looking at the labels.

Comment: This actually sounds like a bug, or at the very least unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @HongOoi: Yes, or more likely, a bug that is old enough that code depends on it, so it has become a feature.

Comment: @HongOoi That's my first thought as well, but I've lurked on the R help/dev mailing lists long enough to know that I'm usually better off not suggesting it unless I'm _really_ sure. ;)

Comment: Probably need to add another entry to R-fortunes along the lines of "factors are really, really strange beasts."